# Nested fetching using github API is returning promises instead of data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch a file description.txt from each folders present in a repository. This is what I have come up with:

```
useEffect(() => {
const apiUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos/afhammk/components/contents`
fetch(apiUrl)
  
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((repos) => {
    console.log("reps",repos)
    
    const s=repos.map((comps)=>{
    let arr=[]
    return {
             name:comps.name , 
             html_url:comps.html_url,
             desc:fetch(comps.url)
                  .then((res)=>res.json())
                  .then((repos)=>repos[0].url)
                  .then((newurl)=>{
                    return(
                      fetch(newurl)
                      .then((res)=>res.json())
                      .then((data)=>{
                           return atob(data.content)
                    })
                    )
                  }
                  )
              
            }
    
    }
    
    )
   
    setAppState(s)
  });
  }, []);
```

But in the output "desc" value is a promise fulfilled with the data instead of only the data.

```
desc: Promise {<fulfilled>: "button"}
html_url: "https://github.com/afhammk/components/tree/main/button"
name: "button"
__proto__: Object
1:
desc: Promise {<fulfilled>: "created:hisham↵description:kkfmkmdkmfkdmkfmdkmkfm↵"}
html_url: "https://github.com/afhammk/components/tree/main/textfield"
name: "textfield"
__proto__: Object
2:
desc: Promise {<fulfilled>: "tree↵"}
html_url: "https://github.com/afhammk/components/tree/main/tree"
name: "tree"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the nesting fetch in a promise
then return this promise

try

```html
useEffect(() => {
  const apiUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos/afhammk/components/contents`
  fetch(apiUrl)

    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((repos) => {
      console.log("reps", repos)

      Promise.all(repos.map((comps) => {
        return fetch(comps.url)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((repos) => repos[0].url)
          .then((newurl) => {
            return (
              fetch(newurl)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  return atob(data.content)
                })
            )
          })
          .then((desc) => {
            return {
              name: comps.name,
              html_url: comps.html_url,
              desc,
            }
          })
      }))
      .then((s)=>{
        setAppState(s)
      })
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: it worked ! Thanks a lot . what was the error in my code ? whenever we use fetch inside a map..should we wrap it in Promise.all ?